# Adding template File in customer account page

Tags: magento-1.7, template, blocks

I am adding one phtml file in customer account dashboard index page. I have used the code as

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
      <block type="ecustomers/myphtml" name="myphtml_page"  after="customer_account_dashboard_hello" template="ecustomers/myphtml.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

And I want to show the phtml after the hello.phtml  in user dashboard.

If I use `<reference name="content">` handle then it shows my phtml content but if I use `<reference name="customer_account_dashboard">`  handle it does not show the my phtml file.

I think we can use the reference for the block which we want to update as I want to update the `customer_account_dashboard` so I referenced it. Please let me know if I am wrong in here.

Comment: is there anyone :) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your xml, apart from the fact that the before="" will have no function here.

The issue is that dashboard block is not a core text list type of block.
Thus the phtml that deals with the dashboard display will not 'magically' output your block.

You need to add an entry to the dashboard.phtml file to echo out your block.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myphtml_page') ?>
```

and place that in the correct position above the code the outputs the hello block

Naturally you will copy the dashboard.phtml file to your theme to make this edit ;)

[image: netbeans debug showing child blocks]

EDIT: Added to answer OP's question about core text list

A core text list is a magento class, which holds a list of child blocks, and will generate a concatenated HTML output of all the child blocks as one HTML block.

a good example of one is 'before_body_end' as define in the layout page.xml file

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
                <label>Page Bottom</label>
            </block>
```

thus, when you assign a child block to a core/text_list derived block, the child's HTML will be generated for you.

you will find the 'magic' in Mage_Core_Block_Text_List::_toHtml()

Comment: Thank youu very much :) ...Enjoying learning magento now ... But I have Questions now ..what does it mean by "core text list type of block" and which tool you are using to see all the variables classes and methods.. sry I am new in programming and magento ... just want to learn everything which i see strange ;) ... thanks again

Comment: The image if from my IDE (netbeans) using xdebug and a breakpoint set on line 29 of the dashboard.phtml file. I prefer netbeans as I use the one IDE for multiple language coding. A popular PHP IDE is PHPStorm. There are more. Try them out, and choose one you like. Using breakspoints with a debugger is an essential for any development, as it allows you to clearly view what is going on in the code at run-time.

Comment: I have expanded on the answer to clarify the core text list blocks

Comment: :) thanks for your very good answer... As I understood  we can Modify the block dynamically or can call block which are structural blocks ... i think it is in the "core text list".. and data blocks can not be modified by using <reference> and calling the block and phtml  file directly so we need to modify the dashboard. php file by coping it in diff theme..Please let me know if I am wrong. And thanks for pointing for new good IDE and xdebug ... I will learn now :)

Comment: Hey I have added new theme so I can edit the dashboard.phtml file but it is still showing the same. Even I edited the customer.xml layout file  <block type="ecustomers/myphtml" name="myphtml_page"  after="customer_account_dashboard_hello" template="ecustomers/myphtml.phtml" />   in which I haved added diret block inside and added in phtml file with

Comment: Sounds like your theme is not being used. You did configure admin to use your theme under system-configuration.

Comment: Yes, I have changed and Even I turned on path hint as well and the theme is working fine as well :) ..Its all coming thrugh my custom themes.Now I am getting confused for which block we can update and which we can not. :(

Comment: I suggest you Google a bit and find a tutorial on how to use themes. It may help clarify thing a bit for you

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just wanted to add that the standard customer account dashboard template has 6 predefined block names: with 'info2' normally being an empty slot. If you add as="info2" (for example) to your block it will render by default.

Comment: @underscorePez I did not know that - thanks for that :)